# wamp server ignore php files

Tags: php, wamp, wampserver

my wamp icon is green and I have access to the project folder.
When I enter to the php file I just see blank white page.

the code :

```
<?php

phpinfo() ;


?>
```

Comment: do you open it by double clicking on it, or by going to `localhost/yourfile.php` in your browser?

Comment: by going to localhost/yourfile.php in my browser

Comment: check your error log then

Comment: the error log is clean but the provlem solved when I made another file in DW and marked "include unicode signature". thank you anyway :)